# Cookie is not being passed onto the next request call

Tags: http, security, authentication, cookies

Issue:
Cookie set between server.com and CLIENT is not being passed to a CNAME server: abc.server.com.

User's Flow:

1. **CLIENT** sends GET request for page data @ request URL **dev.server.com/myapi** for a website that runs on **https://abc.mywebsite.com**
2. **dev.server.com** responds with:

```
Set-Cookie: MYCOOKIE=asdfasdf1; expires=Tue, 04 May 2021 06:59:32 GMT; domain=.server.com; path=/; SameSite = None; secure; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mywebsite.com
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin
```

3. On the CLIENT's browser: client makes a POST to a CNAME **my-cname-host.server.com**

Why isn't the cookie being passed onto this last POST request? It seems domain= is set properly to include the CNAME.

Comment: Are you using `fetch`? What do you have the `credentials` value set as? Share code.

Comment: The call is being made via a thid party package's "submit()" method. Is there a way to mimic the credentials value if I can set custom headers in my third part submit() method?

Comment: No. The `credentials` setting is not a header, it's something that's passed to the `fetch` function directly. Consult the docs/support of your third party package.